# Custom Tumblr theme not working on different blog?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, custom-theme

My HTML/CSS/Javascript knowledge is really limited so i apologize if this question doesn't belong here.

I'm trying to make two portfolio pages on tumblr (one in spanish the other in english) So I used the custom theme: **hasaportfolio** and made some slight changes to the code (like adding two of this pop-up boxes pages: http://painthemes.tumblr.com/pop) the code worked perfectly on the first blog, copied the exact same code to my second blog and is not working like it should.

First of all, the before mentioned pop-up boxes won't open on the second blog and in the top of that the endless scrolling that the theme has is not working at all. Tried the vanilla code from the developer on the second blog and the endless scrolling just doesn't want to work at all. Trying the code that I modify on a html tester (like **htmledit.squarefree)** even if the code is not showing up correctly since it can only work on tumblr, the pop out boxes are working correctly. I contacted to tumblr support and they just didn't wanted to help me since this a custom theme.

Here is a pastebin with the code: pastebin.com/KWXmzJzp

Blog working fine: cesar-ordaz-es(dot)tumblr(dot)com

Troubling blog: cesar-ordaz-en(dot)tumblr(dot)com

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The problem is that the second blog is https://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the second blog is `https://` and some of the content (js files) are loaded over `http://` so they're blocked in your browser. Change the `http://` to `https://` or `//` (the last solution will load the files with the protocol that your site is using, so http for http and https for https)

But since there is no valid SSL here: https://matt.cc/tumblr/portfolio/infinitescroll.js maybe you should post that .js file somewhere else or drop SSL on your domain?

Comment: Hello wanted to thank you since that was the solution! I went to the blog settings in https://www.tumblr.com/settings/blog/ and deactivated the SSL encryption shown here: 
https://68.media.tumblr.com/e40a4b8e6dedd0ed1ff0c1078cd0f031/tumblr_oqq63qa7As1sc79dvo6_r1_1280.png and now both the pop-up boxes and the endless scrolling are working on both blogs!